# Visual guides in IntelliJ code style settings

Tags: intellij-idea

I have set visual guides for 80 in code style settings. However, an example on the right side of the window still has a visual guide on the 38th row.

I just wanted to clarify if 38 is set here for an example or there are some global configs for this.

[image: Wrapping and Braces settings]

Comment: You can hide it from showing in the real editor by unchecking "Appearance -> Show hard wrap and visual guides".

Comment: In the new version it was moved to Editor -> Code Style -> General

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an example so that the indent guide is always visible and you can see the changes to its color.